# User Experience (UX) - latest patterns to represent one-to-many relationship

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design

I have a requirement where there will be a

1. Item - with details like Name and Owner
2. Each Item can have 0 - 50 locations in different statuses.
3. User should be able to add a location for an item.
4. User should be able to edit and delete locations.

I am thinking of a table where each row will have 2 columns - Name and Owner
Expanding a row will display nested table with locations for that item. And, there will be pencil icon or trash icon for edit/delete actions of the location.

Is there a better way to represent this?

Comment: Hey @anv, it should probably get better response(s) if you visualize what an idea you're coming with. Otherwise it's just text and might not necessarily creates the same idealization you tried to describe.

Answer (score 3):

Row expanders are useful if the user needs to compare expanded information among two or more rows. They can become unwieldy when the expansion section becomes large and complex. If you're only showing location and status, though, you can use the horizontal space to preserve vertical space. Cards could work.

[image: 50 location and status pairs in an expander]

An alternative is offering the information in a modal panel such as a side sheet. The user can only engage with location/status information for one item at a time. The user would enter the modal and can then view, edit, and delete each location/status pair.

[image: Location and status shown in a side sheet]

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback and the ideas. I am liking the card layouts for versions and also possibly we can limit the initial display of cards to 2 rows and then user can expand more if they have/want to view more versions.

Comment: Also, this seems to be just appropriate for the users to perform necessary actions.
This is like Accordion Table, right?

Comment: That's right, each row would act like an accordion.

Answer (score 0):

I call your expanding-row pattern a “telescope control,” a relative of the tree control and the “fisheye” view. A telescope has its uses, but there are better alternatives for most cases. The main alternatives for your case:

- **Linked Primary Windows/Pages,** where a link in each Item row opens a new page or window listing the Locations for adding, editing, and deleting. This is best when users typically use the Item just as a stepping stone to “drill down” to some specific Locations of interest (i.e., they’re not working multiple items –they’re just selecting one as a navigation step). It’s also good when you need a Location list page anyway for other tasks (maybe filtered by something other than their related Item), making for a simpler UI.
- **Dialog boxes,** where a control opens a small pop-up that lists the Locations for the Item with current focus. This is not a very convenient design since it can occlude Item data, has no standard means of navigation or saving, and often has to be modal. This is best when the user rarely needs to see or work on Locations and the number of locations tend to be few (i.e., not enough to justify an entire page). With up to 50 locations, I don’t think this is for you.
- **Master-detail regions,** where a region below the Item list is a Location list for whatever Item currently has focus. Basically, instead of putting the Locations immediately below the Item row they belong to, the Locations appear in a dedicated pane separate from the Item list. This is best when the user switches among multiple Items to view, compare, edit, add, and delete Locations.

It looks something like this:
[image]

Compared to the telescope, master-detail regions have the following advantages:

- Depending on the number of Locations, expanding on an Item in a telescope may make its identifying attributes scroll out of view. In a master-detail, with separate scrollable panes for items and locations, the user can see both and will not lose track of the identity of the Item the Locations belong to.
- When studying the Locations of multiple Items, a user may need to scroll and hunt for the Items, whose positions change with each expansion. The master-detail has more stability and it’s easier to keep multiple Items of interest in view.
- In the event the user needs to find an Item with a particular Location (which should be an exception in a properly design window, but it can still happen), the user needs to explicitly expand (and maybe collapse) each Item. For a master-detail, the user only needs to tab down through the Items with an appropriate row-changing key (like the downward cursor key).

However, a telescope may be better than master-detail if:

- You really need to visually emphasize the hierarchical nature of Locations to Items. For a master-detail, it may not be immediately apparent that the Locations “belong” to an Item, so a telescope may be better if users aren’t regularly using the page. On the other hand, if your users are really novices, you probably should go with the Linked Primary Pages with friendly underlined blue links, since that is something users are most likely to understand.
- The levels of hierarchy vary for different items. For example, maybe some Locations also have multiple Process Steps, others have multiple Approvals, and some have both, and some neither. Maybe the user can even create new levels, and levels within those levels, like file hierarchy. It easier to gracefully add arbitrary hierarchy levels to a telescope than a master-detail since a master-detail would need a dedicated area for each subordinate class.

I've a full analysis at [Taking Panes](http://www.zuschlogin.com/?p=31).

BTW, go with [edit-in-place](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74709/view-vs-modify-mode). Don’t make the user click a pencil to modify something. It’s almost never justified from a UX perspective.

Comment: Zuschiag, Thank you very much for your suggestions with detailed notes. 
with Linked Primary Windows/Pages, wouldn't be a additional navigation for the user to view the locations and come back to main page? 

As you mentioned, Dialog boxes many not suit for my use case.

With Master-detail regions,  isn't almost same as expanded or nested table option?
If there are more details to edit (not just the ones displayed as table columns), edit-in-place may not work.

Comment: @anv: Yes, Linked Primary only makes sense if the user typically goes to Locations and doesn't come back to Items (e.g., to choose another Item). Yes, Master-Detail is like a nested table/ telescope, except the nested table doesn't split the superordinate table in two, which is usually a UX improvement. If there are more attributes than in the tables, then you can have additional "overflow" pane(s) for those attributes as described in the Taking Panes link, thus maintaining edit-in-place capability, not to mention allowing the user to simply view those additional attributes.